# How to call a function in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkinsfile, I am taking a branch name as a parameter and need to remove the forward slash. Right now I am doing like this

```
def removeforwardslash(String branchname) {
        return branchname.split('/').join('-')
    }
```

But when I am calling the function I am keeping getting the error.

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

I must be calling the function incorrectly.

```
stages {
    
stage('Build') {
    
    steps{
        sh 'docker build -t test -f test/Dockerfile \
        --build-arg tag=removeforwardslash("$BRANCH_NAME") \
        .'
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message implies that your pipeline believes `removeforwardslash` to be an undefined function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a string in single quotes ' it is:

1. one line
2. not interpolated

You need to enclose  the sh script in triple double quotes """ and interpolate the function call with ${}, like so:

```
sh """docker build -t test -f test/Dockerfile \
    --build-arg tag=${removeforwardslash("$BRANCH_NAME")} ."""
```